# How to compare two strings for accuracy

Tags: vb.net, string, compare, stringcomparer

I'm making this useless program just to get back into programming properly and I'm struggling with comparing two strings for accuracy.

---

I basically have 2 strings: (example)

(Constant that im comparing to) str1 = "abcdefghijkl"

(Input) str2 = "abcdefghjkli"

The str2 is correct up to (and including) "h". I want to know what % of the string is correct.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Private Function compareString(str1 As String, str2 As String)
'Compares str2 to str1 and returns a % match
Dim strNumber As Integer
Dim percentMatch As Integer
'Dim array1(16), array2(16) As Char
'array1 = str1.ToCharArray
'array2 = str2.ToCharArray

 For x = 0 To str1.Length
    'If array1(x) = array2(x) Then
    If str1(x) = str2(x) Then
        strNumber += 1
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
 Next
 percentMatch = ((strNumber / (str1.Length - 1)) * 100)
 percentMatch = CInt(CStr(percentMatch.Substring(0,4)))
 Return percentMatch
```

End Function
The two commented sections are the other approach I tried before coming here. 
The code *should* run as follows

compareString("abcdefghijkl", "abcdefghjkli")

*strNum will get to 8.*

percentMatch = ((8 / 12)*100)

*percentMatch = 75

Return 75

But, its not returning this, On the lines

```
If str1(x) = str2(x) Then
```

it returns an error, "Index was outside the bounds of the array." I understand the error, just not where I am going wrong.

If theres anymore information I can give, I'll do so as soon as I see the notification :)

Thanks in Advance,

Rinslep

Comment: You can't use `str1(x) = str2(x)` if str1 and str2 have differents lenght.

Comment: You're also iterating one index past the end of `str1`. Later on, you're calling `Substring` on a floating point value.

Comment: It breaks on the first iteration through, so even if they were different lengths, surely it wouldnt matter?

Comment: @Engerlost Yep, that fixed it I think. I'll come back in a minute and tell you if I get it working.

Comment: @Rinslep also use `str1.substring(x) = str2.substring(x)` . It's more readeable.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the string

```
str = "ABCDE";
```

str.Length is 5. But if you index it with a 0 based index,

```
str[0] = 'A'
...
str[4] = 'E'
'str[5] throws exception (5 = str.Length)
```

Now in your

```
For x = 0 To str1.Length
```

If you compare with my example, when x is equal to the length of the string, you are checking str[5], which is out of the bound hence throwing the exception.

Change that line to

```
Dim shorterLength = IIf(str1.Length < str2.Length, str1.Length, str2.Length); 'So that you cannot go beyond the boundary
For x = 0 To (shorterLength - 1)
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Ah, forgot to change that back. I tried that and it didn't work. It breaks on the first iteration in the for loop. Could it be that the strings that i'm actually working with are different lengths?

Comment: Okay, if that is the case, you are right. As the two strings are of two different length, the shorter string's index is going out of the bounds. I will update my answer. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Let me guess you converted this from C#. In VB the evaluation operator is either `If(Expression, TruePart, FalsePart)` or `IIf(Expression, TruePart, FalsePart)`.

Comment: Thanks Visual Vincent

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the length of given strings also you should not exceed the bound and also don't exit from loop until checking whole string:

```
Dim x As Integer = 0  
While x < str1.Length AndAlso x < str2.Length
    If str1(x) = str2(x) Then
        strNumber += 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
End While
```

Comment: Why not just do `For x = 0 To Math.Min(str1.Length, str2.Length) - 1`?

Comment: do you see something in question that mentions don't use the solution you provided!!??, your solution is good idea also, but you could propose it in comment instead of asking `Why not....!?` because nobody have not said `do NOT use it`.

Comment: Take it easy... I didn't say that anyone said "do not use it". I just informed you about this little line of code. I do not know anything about your coding abilities or how much you know about loops and the math functions, so I cannot know what you are aware of. I just proposed my code and used the phrase "Why not just..." to let you know about that you can do it this way too, and also meaning that it might be simpler/shorter. I did infact never say that your code was wrong either, because both of our codes does the exact same thing.

Comment: I can rephrase my initial comment if you think it felt a bit offensive.

Comment: it's okay bro, no problem your initial comment are really useful and perfect (as I mentioned), however do whatever convenient to you, good luck.

Comment: Good luck to you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been open for a while but I've been looking into this a little. You would have to respect the length of the strings too. Say you have two strings. `ABCD` and `AEF`. AEF is 75% the length of ABCD. Each letter in ABCD is worth 25%. And there's one letter that's correct in AEF and that's A. And as A = 25%: `75% * 25% = 0,75 * 0,25 = 0,1875 = 18,75%`. String AEF is 18,75% equal to ABCD.

Hope you understood. :)